# populate with condition node Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get workers with action=1 :

```
          Employee.findById(req.user.id)

    .populate({
        path: 'org_permission',
        match: {action:1}

    })
```

here is my code relative org_permission :

```
         var org_permissionSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    org: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Organization'},
    action:Number
},{ _id : false }
 );

 var org_permission = mongoose.model('org_permission', org_permissionSchema);
  module.exports= org_permission;
```

after the query, I don't understand why  I get all results within Employee Model ,  whatever the action value  I give

```
  {
    name:'ysf', 
    worksAt: 
  [ { action: 0, org: 574ec1abf3bd5b59513d1b8e },
    { action: 0, org: 574ec1caf3bd5b59513d1b92 },
    { action: 0, org: 574ec5edc510d23b54c86d12 },
    { action: 1, org: 574ec6776f88549554a11389 }
  ],
```

}

Comment: can you show your employee and organization schema ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your path value in populate() like this;

```
path: 'workAt',
```

Comment: I did that but not working , here is my path declared in my Employee Model  ->           worksAt:[org_permissionSchema].            org_permissionSchema  has two variables : org_id and action , and what I'm trying to do is to get just employees who worksAt: action:0